# Selecting an option in dropdown box dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a dropdown box as given.

```
<select id="selector_states">
    <option value="kl">Kerala</option>
    <option value="tn">Tamil Nadu</option>
    <option value="ka">Karnataka</option>
    <option value="ap">Andhra Pradesh</option>
</select>
```

I need to find the text in the dropdown box with the value of the option given. That is i have "kl" with me in a variable say

```
var state_code="kl"
```

Using this i need to find the text in the select box. I am a python developer and i am not much familiar with jquery. can some one help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are asking?

```
var stateCode = "kl";
var result = $("#selector_states").find("option[value=" + stateCode + "]").text();
alert(result);
```

What the above is doing is:

- find element with id select_states // $("#selector_states") (note: this returns jQuery object)
- from its child DOM elements find ones that are **option** one and have attribute **value** equal to **this ones** $(jQuery object).find("**option**[**value**=**thisOne**] (where this one in your case is stateCode variable.
- find this element and gets its **text()** (or you can type html), for example: `<`html element>**I am the text**`</html element>`, where html element may be `<div>`, `<ul>`, `<li>` etc.

If you are not quite familiar with the stuff I've written above, I recommend reading a bit about DOM tree and how javascript is used to manipulate it. (it will take you about 10 minutes max)

I recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

And keep in mind the examples in the link above are in pure javascript, jQuery is doing the same behind the scenes, is just sugar syntaxed :) (and keep in mind $('html element') is making it jQuery object! (and you can chain functions as we did above $("#selector_states") turns our DOM element into jQuery object. jQuery objects now have **.find** function implemented.. (also **.text()**).

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 3):

Pass your variable to the `.val()` method. jQuery handles the rest:

```
var state_code = 'kl';
$('#selector_states').val(state_code);
```

Note, you won't see any difference here, since `kl` is the default option anyway.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9bovw2oo/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var option = $("#selector_states option[value=" + state_code + "]");
```

This will give you the option with the matching value stored in `state_code`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Select by value
$('select[name="options"]').find('option[value="3"]').attr("selected",true);

// Select by text
//$('select[name="options"]').find('option:contains("Third")').attr("selected",true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<select name="options">
      <option value="1">First</option>
      <option value="2">Second</option>
      <option value="3">Third</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do this

alert($('selector_states').val());